# The tensor product of two simple module of a group algebra

Tags: group-theory, modules, representation-theory

When I browse https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality , I saw it's proof used a fact that $U \otimes _A
 V$ is equal to $\mathbb{C}$ if and only if $V$ and $U$ as representation of $A$ are isomorphism, Where $A=\mathbb{C}[G]$, the group algebra of group $G$. my problem is how to get the  fact.

I think it use the Schur's lemma, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: The way you phrase the question is unclear: to form the tensor product, $U$ must be a right $A$-module, and $V$ a left $A$-module. Rather, $U$ and $V$ should be dual to each other. (Here it's sort of fine because a group algebra is a Hopf algebra, but I'm not sure that was what you had in mind.)

Comment: @Captain Lama Thanks for your comment. But if use Hopf algebra, $U$ and $V$ are tensor over $\mathbb{C}$, and  both as left $A$ module, I don't think this way $U$ and $V$ are dual.